# Jenkins NUnit plugin: How show tests results on job description in Jenkins pileline?

Tags: jenkins, nunit, jenkins-plugins

I have a unit test job on Jenkins and would like to be able to view the test results in jenkins pipeline.

Something like this:

[image: UnitTestJob]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround in the latest version of Jenkins Pipeline:

Edit Pipeline:

[image]

And set to "Show jUnit results"
[image]

The result is like this:

[image]

Yes, the setting is for JUnit, but it was the only solution I found